# Can you explain the meaning of "reference' keyword here

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

```
CREATE TABLE department (dept_no NUMBER(2),  dept_name VARCHAR2(15), mgr_id NUMBER,  FOREIGN KEY (mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id),  mgr_start_date DATE)
```

Comment: A person need to explain the meaning of the reference keyword in the line.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

REFERENCE keyword means that the variable you define in the keyword before (mgr_id), has a pointer to  of real existing table.

In your example mgr_id has a pointer to emp_id on table employee.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions, they should be closed (blocked from answers) (via flag or . See [ask], [answer], [help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.